# JSON array from tag names attr and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Let's suppose, I have this code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span class="toarray" name="someName-1">someDynamicValue</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="toarray" name="someName-2">someDynamicValue</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="toarray" name="someName-3">someDynamicValue</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create JSON array from this code:

```
{
 someName-1: "someDynamicValue", 
 someName-2: "someDynamicValue", 
 someName-3: "someDynamicValue"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like bellow

```
var data = {};

$('span.toarray').each(function(){
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).text();
});

console.log(data);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w08fccty/)

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

Get all the spans with class `toarray`, loop over them, get each spans `text` along with `attr('name')` and push into an object defined above the loop.